# NodeJS. Можно ли увеличить скорость парсинга, оптимизировать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Пишу парсер по выгрузке всех товаров с ozon.ru. Дело в том, что за 12 часов выгрузилось только 16 000 товаров. Это долго.

Вижу, что строчка `var numPages = await this.getNumPages(subCategory2Url);` тормозит все. Она получает кол-во страниц и кол-во всех товаров подкатегории. Если ее убрать и в цикле вместо `page<=numPages[0]` написать `page<=1`, то все выполняется достаточно быстро.

Может можно сделать как-то через while? Чтобы при каждой итерации он не отправлял запрос для получения кол-ва страниц, а просто плюсовал переменную `page`. Но как он узнает, что страницы закончились? Там в api, вроде, если страницы не существует такой, то он начинает с первой.

Вот мой код:

```js
const request = require("request");
const util = require("util");
const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);
const fs = require("fs");
const format = require("node.date-time");
const excel = require("exceljs");
const workbook = new excel.Workbook();
const redis = require('redis');

class Ozon {

    constructor() {
        console.time("startScript");
        this.getAll().then(res=>{
            console.timeEnd("startScript");
        }).catch(e=>{
            console.timeEnd("startScript");
        });
    }

    async getAll() {
        var categories = require("./categories");
        await workbook.xlsx.readFile("xlsx/template_all.xlsx");
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Лист1");
        var row = 2;
        var filename = new Date().format("dd-MM-Y") + ".xlsx";
        for (var id in categories) {
            var mainCategoryName = categories[id].name;                            //имя главной категории
            for (var subc in categories[id].data.categories) {
                var subCategoryId = categories[id].data.categories[subc].id;                 //ID подкатегории
                var subCategoryName = categories[id].data.categories[subc].title;        //имя подкатегории
                for (var subc2 in categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories) {
                    var subCategory2Id = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].id;         //ID 2 подкатегории
                    var subCategory2Name = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].title;         //название 2 подкатегории
                    var subCategory2Url = categories[id].data.categories[subc].categories[subc2].url;       //ссылка на вторую категорию
                    var numPages = await this.getNumPages(subCategory2Url);
                    this.log(mainCategoryName + " > " + subCategoryName + " > " + subCategory2Name + " (" + numPages[0] + ", " + numPages[1] + ")");
                    for (var page = 1; page <= numPages[0]; page++) {
                        var params = {"url": subCategory2Url + "?page=" + page};
                        var res = await this.req("https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v1", params);
                        if (!res.body.catalog.hasOwnProperty("searchResultsV2")) continue;
                        var keys = Object.keys(res.body.catalog.searchResultsV2);
                        var products = res.body.catalog.searchResultsV2[keys[keys.length - 1]].items;
                        for (var product in products) {
                            try {
                                var components = products[product].templateState[1].components;
                                var rating = this.getRating(components) ? this.getRating(components) : 0;
                                var maxItems = this.getMaxItems(components) ? this.getRating(components) : 0;
                            } catch (e) {
                                var rating = 0;
                                var maxItems = 0;
                            }

                            var periods = {"day":"J", "week":"K", "month": "L"};

                            worksheet.getCell("A" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id;
                            worksheet.getCell("B" + row).value = mainCategoryName;
                            worksheet.getCell("C" + row).value = subCategoryName;
                            worksheet.getCell("D" + row).value = subCategory2Name;
                            worksheet.getCell("E" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.title;
                            worksheet.getCell("F" + row).value = products[product].cellTrackingInfo.finalPrice;

                            for(var period in periods) {
                                worksheet.getCell(periods[period]+row).value = await this.getStat(products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id, period, maxItems);
                            }
                            await this.setMaxItems(products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id, maxItems);

                            this.log(products[product].cellTrackingInfo.title + " (" + products[product].cellTrackingInfo.id + ")");
                            row++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            await workbook.xlsx.writeFile("xlsx/all/"+ mainCategoryName+ "_" + filename);

        }
    }

    async getStat(id, period, maxItems) {
        var stat = JSON.parse(await this.rGetValue("stat"));
        var periodsDate = {"day":new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))), "week":new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))), "month":new Date(new Date().getTime() - (31 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)))};
        if(typeof stat[id] !== "undefined") {
            for(var dates in stat[id]) {
                if(stat[id][dates].date == periodsDate[period].format("Y-MM-dd")) {
                    return maxItems - stat[id][dates].value;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    async setMaxItems(id, maxItems) {
        var stat = JSON.parse(await this.rGetValue("stat"));
        if (typeof stat[id] !== "undefined") {
            if (!this.statDateIsset(id)) {
                stat[id].push({date: new Date().format("Y-MM-dd"), value: maxItems});
            }
        } else {
            stat[id] = [{date: new Date().format("Y-MM-dd"), value: maxItems}];
        }
        await this.rSetValue("stat", JSON.stringify(stat));
    }

    async statDateIsset(id) {
        var stat = JSON.parse(await this.rGetValue("stat"));
        var nowDate = new Date().format("Y-MM-dd");
        var res = 0;
        for (var dt in stat) {
            if (stat[dt].date == nowDate) {
                res++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    getRating(components) {
        if (!components) return false;
        for (var component in components) {
            if (components[component].type == "rating") {
                var rating = typeof components[component].commentsCount !== "undefined" ? components[component].commentsCount : 0;
                return rating;
            }
        }
    }

    getMaxItems(components) {
        if (!components) return false;
        for (var component in components) {
            if (components[component].type == "footer") {
                for (var mcomponent in components[component].components) {
                    if (components[component].components[mcomponent].id == "addToCartWithCount") {
                        var maxItems = components[component].components[mcomponent].maxItems;
                        return maxItems;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async getNumPages(category) {
        var res = await this.req("https://www.ozon.ru/api/composer-api.bx/page/json/v1", {"url": category});
        return [res.body.catalog.shared.catalog.totalPages, res.body.catalog.shared.catalog.totalFound];
    }

    rSetValue(key, value) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var clientRedis = redis.createClient();
            clientRedis.set(key, value, function (err, reply) {
                resolve(reply);
                clientRedis.quit();
            });
        });
    }

    rGetValue(key) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var clientRedis = redis.createClient();
            clientRedis.get(key, function (err, reply) {
                clientRedis.quit();
                resolve(reply);
            });

        });
    }


    log(str) {
        console.log("[" + new Date().format("Y-MM-dd HH:mm:SS") + "]: " + str);
        fs.appendFileSync("parser.log", "[" + new Date().format("Y-MM-dd HH:mm:SS") + "]: " + str+"\n");
    }

    req(url, data = []) {
        const options = {
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            qs: data,
            json: true
        };
        return requestPromise(options);
    }
}

var ozon = new Ozon;
```

Буду очень благодарен, если подскажете!

Comment: _Если ее убрать и в цикле вместо page<=numPages[0] написать page<=1, то все выполняется достаточно быстро_  Хм, конечно оно быстро становиться, ведь такой правкой вы начинаете обрабатывать не все страницы, а только одну. Так что проблема не в получении количества страниц, а в том, сколько страниц вы обрабатываете.

Comment: Нет, можно поставить хоть 40. Все равно быстрее обрабатывается. Просто запрос await this.getNumPages(subCategory2Url); замедляет цикл

Comment: Вы время ответа от API смотрели ? Да, возможно этот запрос у озона выполняется медленно. Тогда я бы попробовал получать количества страниц независимо от основного цикла. возможно ко времени окончания обработки страниц одной категории уже будет готов результат по количеству для следующей

Comment: Я вроде нашел решение. Если в ссылку подставить параметр layout_container=categoryMegapagination, то при запросе на вывод товаров из категории приходит еще и nextPage: "категория/?page=X". А если следующей страницы нет, то nextPage будет равняться настоящей страницы. Как теперь это передать в цикл? Проверять через while(page!=nextPage)? Что-то у меня не получается(

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qr8vu0 что-то типа такого
Только в else еще надо page=1

Comment: Я может написал полную хрень здесь, но оно действительно работает. 
http://prntscr.com/qr8yhu

Поправьте, если что не так)